# Dropped tables are not going to Recycle Bin

Tags: oracle, database-tuning

To start, I am a student and just getting my feet wet with Oracle.

Quick history

- Virtual Box XP running Oracle express with SQL Developer.
- Created a user and tablespace for myself. (Key here is I'm not on System)
- I have checked to make sure my Recycle Bin is active with

  > SHOW Parameter recyclebin;

  command.
- I have also tried alter session to on.

Long story short Create table, add some data, drop table with standard drop command with no purge at the end and table does not go to recycle bin and hence can't use the flashback command to retreive it. Any idea as to why my recycle bin would not be functioning as it should, or am I missing something obvious? I am very green so assuming the latter :)
Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Try a "show recyclebin;"  What is returned?

Comment: Is the *flashback command* you refer to = `flashback table TABLE_NAME to before drop`? Also, if you `delete` the table, I wouldn't assume the table going to the recycle bin. The table goes there if you `drop` the table. It really would help if you gave us the *exact* SQL statements you typed in as well as potential error messages returned by Oracle.

Comment: CREATE TABLE PROVINCE_ID

Comment: keep in mind this is very basic as I'm just learning the syntax. CREATE TABLE PROVINCE_ID (ID NUMBER(10) , PROVINCE VARCHAR2(30)); DROP TABLE PROVINCE_ID; FLASHBACK TABLE PROVINCE_ID TO BEFORE DROP; these are the 3 steps I'm doing to try and make sure the recycle bin is working.

Comment: The show recyclebin; command does not do anything, at least nothing I can see...

Comment: The SHOW PARAMETER recyclebin; command gives me name/type/value and the value is set to ON.

Comment: As far as error messages are concerned it just gives me "..the object is not in the recyclebin..."

Comment: I also scanned through the preferences to see if something could possibly be changed in there, but only having a beginners knowledge of Oracle and SQL developer, I couldn't see anything that would cause the above behaviour. I thought about the autocommit, but I believe it only affects commands like Delete, not so much Drop. Either way it made no difference when I tried to turn it on.

Answer (score 3):

Well with some digging on the Doc for Oracle 11g Express, it appears the flashback functionality is not supported. So this would be a good indication of why I'm having problems!!

Comment: Can you provide a reference? My own brief confirms your findings, but I can't find a reference to back it up.  The "Oracle® Database Express Edition 2 Day DBA 11g Release 2 (11.2)" at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/backrest.htm#BABHHIDC has a whole section on recovering dropped tables.  The product editions page (http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/product-editions-066501.html) explicitly says that Flashback Query is available, but Flashback Table, Flashback Database, and Flashback Transaction Query are not available, although it says nothing about Flashback Drop.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#BABJIJCJ is what I was looking at. However it does not refer to flashback drop either. I assumed flashback table was the same feature or at least tied together. Now I'm not so sure...

Comment: I'm not so sure either, particularly because it is working now on my system.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

*Flashback Drop* does work as implied by the documentation for the [Express Edition of 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/backrest.htm#BABHHIDC), but the default configuration needs to be modified to get it to work.

By default XE isn't in ARCHIVELOG mode as shown by...

```
SELECT log_mode FROM v$database;
```

If the query does not return ARCHIVELOG then [follow these instructions to turn it on](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/backrest.htm#CIHDGJAB).

The following expert is from found in [10g Backup and Recovery Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm#sthref641) (strange place, I know) in a section called *Limitations and Restrictions on Flashback Drop*:

> The recycle bin functionality is only available for non-system, locally managed tablespaces. If a table is in a non-system, locally managed tablespace, but one or more of its dependent segments (objects) is in a dictionary-managed tablespace, then these objects are protected by the recycle bin.

Apparently the default tablespace in XE is SYSTEM as seen by the following:

```
SELECT property_value FROM database_properties WHERE property_name='DEFAULT_PERMANENT_TABLESPACE';
```

To determine what the tablespace is for the user you are logged in as, run the following:

```
SELECT user, default_tablespace FROM dba_users WHERE username=user;
```

If the user is a built in account, then you will need to [create a new user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#BJFCGCAA) and assign it to a different tablespace such as USERS.  If your user is already not a built in account, but is using the SYSTEM tablespace, then simply change the default tablespace as follows:

```
ALTER USER myusertoalter DEFAULT TABLESPACE users;
ALTER USER myusertoalter QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Scenario, It works.. just see what i did:-

```
--create table
CREATE TABLE PROVINCE_ID (ID NUMBER(10) , PROVINCE VARCHAR2(30));

select * from user_tables; -- to chk if the table was created and is listed

DROP TABLE PROVINCE_ID; -- Drop the table now

select * from recyclebin; -- see it in recycle bin as some BINXYZ... name

FLASHBACK TABLE PROVINCE_ID TO BEFORE DROP; -- Flash back

select * from recyclebin;-- should be empty if no other tables are there
```

Comment: I wonder if this is something specific to Express version? Some of my other classmates installed full version and seems to work fine for them... azzaxp are you running full install or just Express?